# How can I swap the values of two tuples that do not contain the same number of items?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I have two tuples:

```
tup_1 = ('hello', 'world')
tup_2 = (1, 2, 3)
```

printing both on the same line, I get:

```
('hello', 'world') (1, 2, 3)
```

I want to swap the values of `tup_1` and `tup_2` so that when I now print them on the same line, I get:

```
(1, 2, 3) ('hello', 'world')
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can swap the tuples, just like any other objects,

```
>>> print tup_1, tup_2
('hello', 'world') (1, 2, 3)
>>> tup_1, tup_2 = tup_2, tup_1
>>> print tup_1, tup_2
(1, 2, 3) ('hello', 'world')
```